# I am trying to search using an edit text from firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

It is supposed to show the data and filter when I search but it is not showing any data. I thought I wrote some pretty decent code but I can't find my mistake.

I have a model class with jobTitle, company, experience, age, pay, and type.
I have made a separate layout XML file.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCRtl.png) is the firebase realtime database structure.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGjmZ.png) is the model class.

---

Here is the java code

---

```java
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_showjobs);
            ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("jobs");
    
            searchbtn = findViewById(R.id.searchjobbtn);
            searchtxt = findViewById(R.id.searchjobtxt);
            result = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.results);
            result.setHasFixedSize(true);
            result.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    
            searchbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String searchedText = searchtxt.getText().toString();
                    firebasesearch(searchedText);
                }
            });
        }

        private void firebasesearch(String searchtxt) {
            Query firebaseSearchQuery=ref.orderByChild("jobTitle").startAt(searchtxt).endAt(searchtxt+"\uf8ff");
    
            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<jobclass> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<jobclass>().setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery, jobclass.class).build();
    
    
            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<jobclass, jobviewholder> recycleradaptor = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<jobclass, jobviewholder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull jobviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull jobclass model) {
                    holder.setDetails(model.getJobTitle(), model.getCompany(), model.getPay(), model.getType(), model.getExperience(), model.getAge());
                }
    
    
                @NonNull
                @Override
                public jobviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listlayout, parent, false);
                    jobviewholder jv = new jobviewholder(v);
                    return jv;
                }
            };
            result.setAdapter(recycleradaptor);
            Toast.makeText(showjobs.this, "Searching", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
        }
      /*  @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<jobclass> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<jobclass>().setQuery(ref, jobclass.class).build();
    
            Toast.makeText(showjobs.this, "Searching", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<jobclass, jobviewholder> recycleradaptor = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<jobclass, jobviewholder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull jobviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull jobclass model) {
                    holder.setDetails(model.getJobTitle(), model.getCompany(), model.getPay(), model.getType(), model.getExperience(), model.getAge());
                }
    
    
                @NonNull
                @Override
                public jobviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listlayout, parent, false);
                    jobviewholder jv = new jobviewholder(v);
                    return jv;
                }
            };
            result.setAdapter(recycleradaptor);
        }*/
    
    
        public class jobviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    
            View v;
    
            public jobviewholder(View itemView){
                super(itemView);
                v=itemView;
            }
            public void setDetails(String jobn, String companyn, String pay, String Ag, String xreq, String jtyp){
                TextView jobtitle=findViewById(R.id.jname);
                TextView companyname=findViewById(R.id.cname);
                TextView payment=findViewById(R.id.sal);
                TextView age=findViewById(R.id.agereq);
                TextView exprequired=findViewById(R.id.reqex);
                TextView jobtype=findViewById(R.id.type);
    
                jobtitle.setText(jobn);
                companyname.setText(companyn);
                payment.setText(pay);
                age.setText(Ag);
                exprequired.setText(xreq);
                jobtype.setText(jtyp);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Thank you for your time. I hope someone can help me find the problem.

Comment: Instead of onclicklistner try Onvalueeventlistener

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo added the pic in the description.

Comment: @ABHIRAMAREDDYREDDY Have you tried to start listening for changes?

Comment: I am sorry but i dont understand how to do that

Answer (score 0):

```
result.setAdapter(recycleradaptor);
            Toast.makeText(showjobs.this, "Searching", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to this `recycleradaptor` you have to start listening as well.You have to do that in `onStart()`

So you can do

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    recycleradaptor.startListening();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the working code for search using Firebase database`

```
   private void  searchFriend(String text_search) {
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.USERS)
            .orderByChild("name")
            .startAt(text_search)
            .endAt(text_search + "\uf8ff");


    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<User> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
            .setQuery(query, User.class)
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .build();

    searchAdapterQuery = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final UserViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final User user) {
            holder.userName.setText(user.getName());

          

                }


                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.all_user_recycler_view_item, viewGroup, false);

            return new UserViewHolder(itemView);
        }
    };

    searchAdapterQuery.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapterQuery);
}`
```